# find value but replace another in another line via bash

Tags: bash, perl, sed, grep, gawk

I have to move some pages to another host, but the db IPs got split up.
So I have to do find a value of a username and replace two lines above the IP

I tried it with this:

```
#!/bin/bash

OUTPUT="$(find /home/user/files/script/test-file -maxdepth 1 -iname  file_with_many_sqlconnections.php -exec grep -Hina -B 2 u1_3347 {} \; | grep 172)"

echo "${OUTPUT}"

LINE="$(echo "$OUTPUT" | cut -d"-" -f3 )"
echo "${LINE}"

FILE="$(echo "$OUTPUT" | cut -d"-" -f1,2)"

echo "${FILE}"

CONTENT="$(echo "$OUTPUT" | cut -d"-" -f4 | cut -d"." -f4 | cut -d "\"" -f1)"

echo "${CONTENT}"

gawk -v line="$LINE" -v content="$CONTENT" -v file="$FILE" -i inplace "NR=="line"{gsub("content", 177)}1" "$FILE"
```

I tried it with several combinations of variables, quotevariants and vice versa.
I also tried `sed` and `perl`, but either I got garbage as output, issues with line break after `EOF`, or `gawk` ignores the linebreak and tries to stuff everything in one command.

I used the `echo` segments only for viewing if the results of the results are okay, and as I see it in the shell, it "displays" it fine.

Issue

```
  $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.178",
     "u2_3456","pass6");


    $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.178",
     "u1_3347","pass7");


    $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.178",
     "u1_3347","pass7");


    $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.178",
     "u2_3456","pass6");


    $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.178",
     "u1_3347","pass7");
```

Should be:

```
 $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.178",
  "u2_3456","pass6");


 $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.180",
  "u1_3347","pass7");


 $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.180",
  "u1_3347","pass7");


 $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.178",
  "u2_3456","pass6");


 $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.180",
  "u1_3347","pass7");


 $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.180",
  "u1_3347","pass7");
```

Issue

```
  $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.178",
     "u2_3456","pass6");


    $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.178",
     "u1_3347","pass7");
```

Comment: Please add a sample i/p and proper expected output/

Comment: Why is this tagged 'perl'?

Comment: I put it to pastebin, as I got a formattingussue here
http://pastebin.com/62XG4jkw
  I tried it with perl too, so it was a mistake in that case, sorry

Comment: Please explain the formatting issues you experienced. Especially explain what is wrong about the formatting I applied by clicking the obvious button `{}`. If you cannot explain, please study the StackOveflow formatting help.

Comment: I see a contradiction between your phrasing "two lines above" and the quotes you provided.

Comment: Please explain the third parts of the quotes you provided in paste bin.

Comment: Your "shouldbe" has six entries, but your first "Issue" only 5.

Answer (score 0):

Working on your sample input (i.e. skipping the file reading etc.):

```
perl -0777 -pe "s/(\$db = mysql_connect\()\"\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+(\",\s*\n)\s*(\"u1_3347\")/ \1\"172.1.1.180\2  \3/g"
```

Details:

- use `-0777` to eat the input completely,
  allowing patterns to match across newline
- `-pe` for looping over input and printing result by default
- look for pretty much any IP address,
  embedded in the characteristic other parts of the desired input lines
- look for specifically that user which needs the IP changed
- assemble new outputlines from whitespaces, capture groups and new IP
- everywhere `g`

Output (as desired, apart from whitespace tinkering and having only the five entries of your sample input):

```
  $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.178",
     "u2_3456","pass6");


     $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.180",
  "u1_3347","pass7");


     $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.180",
  "u1_3347","pass7");


    $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.178",
     "u2_3456","pass6");


     $db = mysql_connect("172.1.1.180",
  "u1_3347","pass7");
```